# TCPDF use within Cakephp

Tags: tcpdf, cakephp-2.3

There are a lot posts about this subjects, but the link to any sloution are not working anymore... I followed [this](http://murado.blogspot.nl/2014/06/creating-pdf-files-with-cakephp-and.html) article.
I downloaded TCPDF master.
Upzipped it in the folder Vendor/ tcpdf
Eddited xtcpdf.php

```
<?php
App::import('Vendor','tcpdf/tcpdf');

class XTCPDF extends TCPDF{

}
```

Edit config.php (is this the right path?
/**
 * Installation path (/var/www/tcpdf/).
 * By default it is automatically calculated but you can also set it as a fixed string to improve performances.
 */
define ('K_PATH_MAIN', '/var/www/ppp/app/Vendor/tcpdf');

```
/**
 * URL path to tcpdf installation folder (http://localhost/tcpdf/).
 * By default it is automatically set but you can also set it as a fixed string to improve performances.
 */
define ('K_PATH_URL', 'http://localhost/ppp/Vendor/tcpdf');
```

Create app/View/Layouts/pdf/default.ctp

```
    <?php

header("Content-type: application/pdf");

echo $content_for_layout;
?>
```

Then in the webpages controller:

```
public function newpdf(){

    $users = $this->User->find('all');

    $this->set(compact('users'));

    $this->layout = '/pdf/default';

    $this->render()->type('application/pdf');

}
```

and in de view/webcontroller

```
public function newpdf(){

    $users = $this->User->find('all');

    $this->set(compact('users'));

    $this->layout = '/pdf/default';

    $this->render()->type('application/pdf');

}
```

When i want to test it i get a blank page, without anything...

- I made the function in Webpages. Is that all right? Or should I make the function somewhere else?
- The path in the configuration file, I work on a localhost on linux. The path: `/var/www/ppp/app/Vendor/tcpdf`. Is that the right path?
- The URL is set is `http://localhost/ppp/app/Vendor/tcpdf` Is that the right URL?
  Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add to the question the relevant code, the function you made and so on.

Answer (score 0):

first of all did you checked whether the tcpdf is loaded or not

```
App::import('Vendor','tcpdf',array('file' => 'tcpdf/tcpdf.php'));
```

then on path where you want to put the pdf.It must be the real path

```
$path=realpath('../webroot/pdf/') . '/';
```

then initialize the tcpdf

```
$pdf= new tcpdf();
```

then set desired file options

```
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Your Name');
$pdf->SetTitle(title);
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF');
$pdf->SetKeywords(keywords);
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
```

then get the html which you want to convert to pdf

```
$html= $this->render('/Elements/Pdf');
```

write the html to pdf

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

then output it

```
$name='pdf.pdf';
$pdf->Output($path.$name, 'F');
```

Let me know if still have some issues.

Comment: On the site there is also CakePDF, wich also not worked. Yesterday i solved that and with that also the mean problem of TCPDF.